# playing with wrong two cards

Tags: texas-hold-em, no-limit, home-game, dealing

home game - we play two decks to be more efficient (red deck / blue deck rotating).

9 players around the table. one of the plays..

pre flop 5 players call BB.

flop comes 234. one player goes all in. the other calls (not all in). everyone else fold.

all in has KK, the other has 88. board is 2 3 4 5 J

KK wins and take the pot. that moment one of the not involved players realize that 88 plays with red cards while the blue deck is being played. apparently it is the exact previous hand of the player with 88.

his real cards (blue deck) is also in front of him face down. they are 96. makes him straight and beating KK.

how do you resolve this issue pls. who wins? do you cancel the play? how do you split the pot? how about all other players who called BB and folded after player with 88 called all in of player with KK.

best regards,

Comment: KK doesn't win here, it's a straight on board (A-2-3-4-5). The best action would be to either split the pot, reversing the hand (paying everyone what they initially paid), or punishing the player with 8-8 as he was potentially foul-playing.

Comment: Thank you what if board is not straight. So if KK wins?

Comment: I think the 96 is live and wins.  The proper hole cards are known. Playing the wrong cards is not an advantage as he was playing the hand blind.

Comment: @Seth, you may have misread OPs post he wrote the board was 2 3 4 5 J not A-2-3-4-5, not a straight on board

Comment: @Jon The question was edited after my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If this were to happen in a casino it would be declared a misdeal and they would try to refund the money of everyone that had something invested.

this is unlike the situation where someone who had the wrong number of cards and their hand would be declared dead and action would continue

Answer (score 0):

In the situation as you've described it there is no straight.  KK wins regardless.  As to what to do, that's up to house rules.

Comment: 6 makes a straight